# Angular 4 sending message to service but got back undefined

Tags: angular

I'm working on a contacts page, where user can send me an email message. Upon successful send, the user should be redirected to a "message sent" page, which, of course, should only be visible if they have already sent message.

I'm trying this using services, but it's not working.

**the send method**

In the `ContactComponent`, the method that sends the email is defined thus:

```
sendEmail() { 
    if (/^([a-z]@[a-z]).[a-z]$/.test(this.emailMessage.sender.email)) { 
      this.handleError("Bad email")
      return;
    }
    this.emailSender = (this.contactService
      .send(this.emailMessage))
    this.emailSender
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.code === 200) { 
          // post the data to the "Message Sent" service"
          this.messageSentService.announceMessageSent(res.message)
          // TODO: nativate straight to the success page
          // this.router.navigate(['messageSent'])
          this.router.navigateByUrl('contact/messageSent')
        }
        else {
          this.handleError(res.message)
        }
      })
  }

  private handleError(cause : string) { 

    //  show error message either somewhere in the form or as a modal
    this.formError = cause;
  }
```

**MessageSentService**

Is defined thus:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class MessageSentService { 
    // services, solely to announce the message has been successfully sent
    private messageSentService = new Subject<string>();

    // Observable string streams
    messageSent$ = this.messageSentService.asObservable();

    // service message command
    announceMessageSent(successMessage : string) { 
        this.messageSentService.next(successMessage);
    }

    announceMessageFail() { 
        this.messageSentService.next();
    }
}
```

I use a `MessageSentComponent` which is protected by a `MessageSentGuard`

**message-sent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageSentService } from '../../../services/message-sent.service';
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from '../../../auto-unsubscribe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-sent',
  templateUrl: './message-sent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-sent.component.css']
})
@AutoUnsubscribe
export class MessageSentComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(private messageSentService: MessageSentService) { 
    this.subscription = this.messageSentService
      .messageSent$
      .subscribe(message => { this.message = message;})
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**message-sent-guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from "../auto-unsubscribe";
import { MessageSentService } from "../services/message-sent.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
@AutoUnsubscribe
export class MessageSentGuard implements CanActivate{

    subscription : Subscription;
    message : string;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private service : MessageSentService ) {
            // initiate subscription
            this.subscription = this.service
                .messageSent$
                .subscribe(message => this.message = message);
            console.log("in the constructor, message === %s",
                this.message)
        } 
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot) { 
        console.log("message === %s", this.message)
        // if a message hasn't been sent, this has no business activating
        if (!this.message) { 
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            return false;
        }
        // send the message back, so that MessageSentComponent can get it 
        this.service.announceMessageSent(this.message);
        return true; 
    }

}
```

**Expected behavior**

As a user, when I go to contacts page and successfully send email, I should be greeted with "Your message has been sent!" page.

**Actual behavior**

It tries to redirect to that page, but the `MessageSentGuard` prevents it, because when it tries to hit `MessageSentService`, it's getting `undefined` for the `message`. I verified it by `console.log`ging it:

[image]

Why is this happening?!

**UPDATE**: It's probably not important (as the only use this would serve is to re-state the fact that `MessageSentComponent` is protected by `MessageSentGuard`), but here is the `app.routing.ts`:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { AboutComponent } from "./components/dashboard/about/about.component";
import { ContactComponent } from "./components/dashboard/contact/contact.component";
import { MessageSentComponent } from "./components/dashboard/message-sent/message-sent.component";
import { MessageSentGuard } from "./guards/message-sent-guard";

export const routes : Routes = [
    {
        path : '',
        redirectTo : 'home',
        pathMatch : 'full'
    },
    {
        path : 'home',
        component : HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'about',
        component : AboutComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'contact',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ContactComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'messageSent',
                component: MessageSentComponent,
                // TODO: implement a guard on this component, that checks for "message sent" status data. 
                // if there isn't any, it should bounce to ContactComponent
                canActivate: [MessageSentGuard]
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: '',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        path : '**',
        redirectTo : 'home'
    }
];
```

Comment: The `this.service.messageSent$` is asynchronous, so you need to wait until it is finished before `this.message` will be set. Alternately, the `canActivate` function may return an `Observable`, so you may want to try that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a good approach to the problem you are trying to solve.
The way I see it:

1. you go to contact page, showing the contact form
2. user clicks send: contact form disappears, indeterminate loader shows
3. user gets feedback (message sent or not)

In no point the route changes.

Otherwise:

**message-sent-guard.ts**

```
export class MessageSentGuard implements CanActivate{

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private service : MessageSentService ) {
        } 

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot) { 
        return this.service.messageSent$.pipe(
            first(),
            map(msg => !!msg),
            switchMap(sent => {
                if (!sent) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                    return NEVER;
                }
                return of(true);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

In order for it to work, you need to emit the event after you change the route or make the subject replayable (using `new ReplaySubject(1)` in the service), so that it emits again the last message on each new subscription.

Comment: If the message attempt fails, they stay on that contacts page, but are greeted with an error in the form. 

Thanks for coming up with this so quickly! I'll take a look at it when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: [Here's what happens when I just copy that code over and load any of the pages](https://imgur.com/a/ImZS3OZ)

Comment: @MikeWarren is your MessageSentService injectable? Is it exposed via a module or? It seems that angular can't resolve the arguments for the guard which are 2 (Router and MessageSentService).

Comment: Mine was `@Injectable()` but I simply copy-and-pasted what you came up with and included the necessary dependencies. I'll give it another try when I get home

Comment: same error. I can't seem to get anywhere. Am I supposed to `next()` from just `MessageSentService`, because that's what I'm doing.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the error to go away, by making `MessageSentGuard` `@Injectable()`. Problem is that, now, its `canActivate` does not seem to be hit. Time to roll out the TDD

Comment: UPDATE: It happens just fine in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jewstk), but I'm unable to replicate the results in the real thing

Comment: @MikeWarren Try debugging the "real thing". You can use `tap` operator to add `console.log` or `debugger` statements inside your observables.

Comment: Apologies for the ongoing necro-commenting, but I have tried and tried, but have failed to resolve this issue. I try `tap` but get `ReferenceError` at runtime. I try putting the caveman debugging (`console.log` statements) inside the `switchMap` callback, but none of them are being hit. However, any `console.log` that I place right before this returned Observable, is getting hit, which means this function is really getting hit. 

I confirm this, by making my `ContactService` more loosely-coupled via abstract class, and implementing and using a `FakeSenderService` instead of the real one.

Comment: Even when I slip in a `console.log(msg)` in that `map` callback, it fails to execute.

Comment: That means that `messageSent$` does not emit anything. Did you call `next`, is it a replayable? Maybe the message is lost...

Comment: [Here is the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/MikeWarren2014/OpenSourceRoadsSite)

Comment: @MikeWarren in your `contact.component.ts` you provide `MessageSentService`. This means that component will create a new instance of the service for itself different than the one the guard uses... Remove it from the providers